# Rを使用して列の値を他の列にあるNAに置き換えたい

Tags: r, tidyverse, rstudio

Rを使用してデータをクリーニングしています。
下記に3つの列（ID, s1, s2）があり、s1には2つの欠測があります。
s1に欠測がある場合、s2の同じ行をNAに置き換えた列を作成したいのですが、どなたかおしえていただけますか？

ID　　s1　　s2
1　　　2　　 1
2　　　3　　 1
3　　　2　　 3
4　　 NA　　 2 ← ここにs1のNAを入れたい
5　　 NA　　 2 ← ここにs1のNAを入れたい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` を使う場合。

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:5, s1 = c(2, 3, 2, NA, NA), s2 = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2)
)

df <- df %>% mutate(s2 = replace(s2, is.na(s1), NA))
df

#
  ID s1 s2
1  1  2  1
2  2  3  1
3  3  2  3
4  4 NA NA
5  5 NA NA
```